# Issue while saving collection into csv using powershell

Tags: csv, powershell, powershell-3.0

I have below powershell code using which am saving results into csv file but I couldnt save them in csv file.

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.AnalysisServices")

$SSASServerName = "SSAS_ServerName"
$SSASDB = "TESTDB"

$SSASServer = New-Object Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Server
$SSASServer.Connect($SSASServerName)
$SSASDatabase = $SSASServer.Databases.Item($SSASDB)
$SSASDatabase.Roles | Select-Object Name, Members | Export-Csv C:\dev\psout\test.Csv
pause
```

This script extracts name of the role and members associated to that role. one role can have multiple members.

I tried above script, it exports role but in Members field, I see string "Microsoft.AnalysisServices.RoleMemberCollection" for all the roles.

If I do not export to csv, I can view the members in either ps window or text file.

what am i missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only export values that can be represented as a string to a csv-file. `Members` is a collection-object that may include multiple `RoleMember`-objects, so you need use a calculated property to access the `Name`-property inside each `RoleMember`. How to approach this depends on the desired output.

You can join the objects Name-property to a single string

```
$SSASDatabase.Roles |
Select-Object Name, @{n="Members";e={ ($_.Members | % { $_.Name }) -join '; '}} |
Export-Csv C:\dev\psout\test.Csv -NoTypeInformation


Role1,"User1; User2"
Role2,"User3; User4"
```

Or you could make one row in the csv-file "per row per member" which I usually prefer since it's easier to filter in Excel.

```
$SSASDatabase.Roles | ForEach-Object {
    #Store role-reference so we can access it later inside the member-foreach
    $r = $_
    $r.Members | ForEach-Object {
        #Store member-reference so it's available inside Selec-Object
        $m = $_
        $r | Select-Object Name, @{n="Member";e={ $m.Name }}
    }
} | Export-Csv C:\dev\psout\test.Csv -NoTypeInformation


Role1,User1
Role1,User2
Role2,User3
...
```

Comment: Hi Frode, I would like to print $SSASServerName itself in the output for all the rows, where should I place this variable? I tried putting in select list, but it doesnt work.

Comment: You need to use a calculated property for evey type of value that is not a property of a `Roles`-object. So try `Select-Object Name, @{n="ServerName";e={ $SSASServerName }}, @{n="Members";e={ ($_.Members | % { $_.Name }) -join '; '}}`

Comment: Thanks Frode for the info!